# Referencing Two Tables in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

So the question is asking this:

List the order number and order date for each order that was placed by Johnson's Department Store, but does not contain and order line for a Gas Range.

Below is what I already tried and the error it keeps giving me. So I know I am supposed to select the ORDER_NUM and ORDER_DATE because that it what it's asking to list. I put from ORDERS because that's where ORDER_NUM and ORDER_DATE are, and I put part because that was the only place where I could find Gas Range as data being inserted. 608 is the customer number for Johnson's Department Store, and the last line is what I cannot figure out. How do I say the description does not contain Gas Range?

```
SELECT ORDER_NUM, ORDER_DATE
    -> FROM ORDERS, PART
    -> WHERE CUSTOMER_NUM='608'
    -> AND PART.DESCRIPTION NOT IN 'Gas Range';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Gas Range'' at line 4
```

Answer (score 3):

`NOT IN` does not work as you expect it here. (it's used along with a set of values)

You need `PART.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '%Gas Range%'`

Comment: This runs when I type it in, and lists the two that it is supposed to list, but for some reason it is listing them multiple times, any idea why?

Comment: @Steberz Because you are joining two tables. So each record will be matched with each other record. You need a join-condition to get unique rows. maybe `where part.order_id = order.id` (But most likely there is a dedicated table for this, cause part to order would be n:n I guess. Hard to tell without knowing your database.)

Answer (score 1):

Use NOT LIKE instead of NOT IN

```
SELECT ORDER_NUM, ORDER_DATE
    -> FROM ORDERS, PART
    -> WHERE orders.id = part.order_id and CUSTOMER_NUM='608'
    -> AND PART.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '%Gas Range%';
```

The IN operator allows you to specify multiple values in a WHERE clause.

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (value1,value2,...);
```

The LIKE operator is used in a WHERE clause to search for a specified pattern in a column.

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name LIKE pattern;
```

The "%" sign is used to define wildcards (missing letters) both before and after the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the operator <>.
I also noticed that there is no join condition between the two tables.

```
SELECT ORDER_NUM, ORDER_DATE
    -> FROM ORDERS, PART
    -> WHERE CUSTOMER_NUM='608'
    -> AND PART.DESCRIPTION <> 'Gas Range';
```

Comment: Same thing as the other answers. It runs and gives me the two pieces of data it is supposed to, but for some reason it lists them both multiple times... Any idea why?

Comment: You need to make a join between ORDERS and PART. Use primary key from PART with foreign key from ORDERS.

Comment: Could you show me that? Are you saying to UNION them?

Comment: Something like:
SELECT ORDER_NUM, ORDER_DATE FROM ORDERS, PART WHERE ORDERS.PART_ID = PART.PART_ID AND CUSTOMER_NUM='608' AND PART.DESCRIPTION <> 'Gas Range';